# Dash DataTable with individual formatting of certain cells

Tags: python, pandas, datatable, plotly-dash, conditional-formatting

I am visualizing a Pandas DataFrame in a **Dash DataTable** and would like to **manually highlight** certain **cells** with a **specific color** (e.g., red or green).

The coloring depends on some conditions which are not simply dependent on the value of the cell itself but on neighboring values (e.g., the difference between the previous and the next row).

I have gone through the [docs](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/style) and [reference](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/reference).
From my understanding [conditional formatting](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/conditional-formatting) does not allow to introduce conditions which do depend on values of neighboring cells.

Is there a way to define the conditions in Python using the Pandas DataFrame and then format certain specific cells of my Dash DataTable accordingly?
I have looked into the [`style_cell` property]](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/style) but this seems to be applied to the entire table and cannot be applied on a cell-by-cell basis.

**Edit**:
To be more precise, what I am looking for is to color the values of each cell depending on the cell value of the next row [see example in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sIRc.png):

- when the value of a cell is **greater** than the value of the cell in the next row (e.g., row1 @ col1 > row2 @ col1) then the text color should be **green** (e.g., row1 @ col1)
- when the value of a cell is **lower** than the value of the cell in the next row (e.g., row2 @ col1 < row3 @ col1) then the text color should be **red** (e.g., row2 @ col1)
- when the value of a cell is **equal** to the value of the cell in the next row (e.g., row1 @ col2 = row2 @ col2) then the text color should not change / remain **black** (e.g., row1 @ col2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can find different between rows in pandas first then use this to style your dash datatable. Below is my code:

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import numpy as np
data = OrderedDict(
    [("col1", [3, 1,2]),
     ("col2", [3, 3, 1]),
     ("col3", [1, 3, 3]),
    ])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['col_1_shift'] = df['col1'] - df['col1'].shift(-1)
df['col_2_shift'] = df['col2'] - df['col2'].shift(-1) 
df['col_3_shift'] = df['col3'] - df['col3'].shift(-1) 
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

And here is the df Ouput:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col_1_shift col_2_shift col_3_shift
0   3   3   1   2.0 0.0 -2.0
1   1   3   3   -1.0    2.0 0.0
2   2   1   3   0.0 0.0 0.0
```

After that we will style based on col_shift columns:

```
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])


#print(df)
app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    
    #sort_action='native',
    columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns[0:3]],
    style_data_conditional=[
        {'if': {'filter_query': '{col_1_shift} > 0',
                'column_id': 'col1'
            },
            'color': 'green'
        },
                {'if': {'filter_query': '{col_1_shift} < 0',
                'column_id': 'col1'
            },
            'color': 'red'
        },
                {'if': {'filter_query': '{col_2_shift} > 0',
                'column_id': 'col2'
            },
            'color': 'green'
        },
                {'if': {'filter_query': '{col_2_shift} < 0',
                'column_id': 'col2'
            },
            'color': 'red'
        },
                {'if': {'filter_query': '{col_3_shift} > 0',
                'column_id': 'col3'
            },
            'color': 'green'
        },
                {'if': {'filter_query': '{col_3_shift} < 0',
                'column_id': 'col3'
            },
            'color': 'red'
        },
        
    ] 
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: from my understanding your suggestion compares the data of a different row ('B') for conditional formatting of rows ('A').
what I need is to format the cell in the current row depending on the difference in value of the current vs previous row.

a possible solution would be to use the solution you suggest and introduce an additional but hidden row with a value that controls the formatting of the cell in question.

Comment: @Fab.B: My suggestion is comparing data of different columns, not row. Can you provide you code, or the Output you want?

Comment: see edit and image in initial post

Comment: Works perfectly. I have just slightly modified the code by hiding the columns using the `hidden_columns` argument. 

probably worth noting that in `style_data_conditional` hidden columns need to be "addressed" with curly brackets (i.e., `{hidden_column_id}`) vs non-hidden columns without brackets (i.e., `non_hidden_column`)